# Azure B2C - MSAL - Fetch ID Token with updated claims

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure B2C using built in signup/signin policy to register and sign in user. I have a react application, in which I have implemented the flow using msal library. Now in one of my scenario, I am aware that the claims data has been updated and I want to update my id token in browser order to get the latest claims. I have tried using acquireTokenSilent but it is not returning token with latest claims.

What shall I do in order to get token with latest claims?

Answer (score 1):

Claims are not dynamic.

The only way to do this is to log out and then log in.

This is not particuler to B2C. ADFS e.g. does exactly the same.

Comment: ok, lemme provide details. I have implemented edit profile in my app via loginPopup(editProfileAuthority) of msal, on success new ID token is returned with new claims but problem is now in browser there are 2 ID tokens, one generated via login and other via edit profile. Login one has old claims and edit profile has new claims. Is there anyway I can remove the ID token generated via login from browser(since the key is random everytime, I am not able to directly remove it) or is there any other solution. On reading your comment, looks like logout after edit profile is the only solution.